# alarm is getting fired today at 12 AM rather then after 48 hours

Tags: android, android-alarms

i am firing my alarm at 12 AM midnight after every 48 hours (i.e. two days).

here is my code

```
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR,  12); // MIDNIGHT 12 AM
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,00);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

            calendar.getTime().toString();

            dayAlarmMgr.setRepeating(
                    AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
                    calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 2,  // EVERY TWO DAYS
                    dayAlarmIntent);
```

now when i run the application my alarm fires today at 12 AM but it should gets fire after 48 hours right as per the requirement.

so how can i make it fire after 48 hours at 12 a.m. only ?

Comment: Hour 0 is midnight. 12 is noon.

Comment: `calendar.add( Calendar.HOUR, 48 );` doesn't do it?

Comment: that's what `calendar.getTimeInMillis(),` does, it is the initial trigger time.

Comment: @kevskree: `HOUR` does not specify AM or PM, so it depends on the current time (unless the weird AM/PM convention specifies that 0 is always midnight, but I was under the impression that midnight was 12AM)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add 2 days to the first time the alarm will go off.  You should also use `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` as it is more straight-forward.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0); // MIDNIGHT 12 AM
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,00);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 48);

dayAlarmMgr.setRepeating(
        AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
        calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 2,  // EVERY TWO DAYS
        dayAlarmIntent);
```

Comment: can you explain `calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 48)` please ?

Comment: It adds 48 hours (2 days) to the time the calendar is set to.  This ensures that the first time the alarm goes off is midnight 2 days from now.

Comment: okay , one more thing , i am setting this alarm in `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` whenever user reboots the device his time starts from now ?

Comment: But doesnt the 2 parameter in setRepeating say the time at which the alarm should first go off...Official documentation says "time in milliseconds that the alarm should first go off, using the appropriate clock".